# Javascript rendering [object Object] as string data type

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, types

I've been trying to solve this for a while now. Here's my JS class:

````
class Comment {
        constructor(comment) {
            
            this.id = comment.id
            this.comment = comment
        }
    
        static createComment(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            const commentMessage = e.target.children[0].value
            const commentList = e.target.previousElementSibling
            
    
            Comment.submitComment(commentMessage, commentList)
            e.target.reset()
        }
    
        renderComment(commentList){
            const p = document.createElement('p')
            p.dataset.id = this.id
            p.innerText = "- " + this.comment + " "
        }
    
        static submitComment(commentMessage, commentList){
    
            fetch(commentsURL, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    comment: commentMessage
                }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(comment => {
                let newComment = new Comment(comment)
                newComment.renderComment(commentList)
            })
        
        }
}```
````

Which returns the following error from my Rails API:

"NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "comment":String):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:24:in `comment_params' app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:8:in` create'"

And here's that controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        comments = Comment.all
        render json: comments
    end

    def create
        comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        if comment.save
            render json: comment
        else
            render json: {errors: comment.errors.full_messages}
        end
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
    end
end
```

Any help is welcome and I'll try to keep it as clear as needed.

Comment: Solved it myself, just by adding a "text" attribute as a string type, on my database. That simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ruby controller is trying to do an operation to the return string which is not a valid method. Where did you get the `.permit()` from? Maybe ask in a ruby forum?

The reason it is returning [Object object] is because you are expecting a json object in your fetch request. You would usually just render the string that is returned from one of the values in the json object, but in this case it is an error object.

Answer (score 1):

You post your comments with this:

```
fetch(commentsURL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        comment: commentMessage
    }),
})
```

That means that you're sending JSON like `{ "comment": "Comment text goes here..." }` to Rails.

Then over in Rails you try to unpack that with this:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
```

That's says "the parameters must have `comment` field and within that `comment` field look for the `comment` field". So that's looking for JSON like this:

```
{
  "comment": {
    "comment": "Comment text goes here.."
  }
}
```

So change your JSON to match your parameter parsing:

```
JSON.stringify({
  comment: { comment: commentMessage }
})
```

or change your parameter parsing to match your JSON:

```
params.permit(:comment)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did some refactoring on the API to make it less redundant. But apparently the error is now coming from the front end. It keeps returning [object Object] instead of a string. 
I've been trying to solve it for days now and I'm very frustrated.
If you want to get deeper into it, feel free to check the entire repo:
https://github.com/Roeck/TEST1

Comment: So what exactly is `commentMessage` on the JavaScript side?

Comment: "commentMessage" was an attribute I've used attempting to specify the string data type, if that makes sense. I've just removed it, it made no difference. Detail: inside my constructor, I have "this.comment = comment" which renders " [object Object]". If I remove this line, it renders "undefined". If I use "this.comment = comment.id", it obviously returns the index number of the submitted comment. Seems like we're very close to the solution

Comment: But `createComment` calls `submitComment` and that's just grabbing `e.target.children[0].value`. So why is `e.target.children[0].value` a JavaScript stringified object?